# Construction "Class<? extends SomeType>" variable declaration in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, class, extends

I am just curious about whether declaring a variable in a way known from Java is possible in Objective-C:

```
Class<?extends SomeType>
```

For example: I have a class called MyClass. It has a static method

```
+ (void)myMethod
```

It has also two subclasses: MySubclassA and MySubclassB. I have such code:

```
Class myClass;
if(<some condition>) {
  myClass = [MySubclassA class];
} else {
  myClass = [MySubclassB class];
}
[myClass myMethod];
```

This code works fine, there are no compiler warnings, but I am just curious whether the construction I mentioned is somehow present in Objective-C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C does not have templates (like C++) or generic types with type erasure (like Java) or runtime generic types (like C#). Unlike these languages, Objective-C messages are dynamically dispatched at runtime (instead of bound at compile time). Thus, many of the systems for producing type-agnostic code in C++, Java or C# are unnecessary. Objective-C prefers "duck-typing" whereby any object that responds to a given selector (message) can be given that message by calling code, regardless of the receiving object's type. Since classes are objects in Objective-C, the same is true for class methods as for instance methods.

So, given

```
@interface MyClassA : NSObject
{}
 - (void)someMethod;
@end

@interface MyClassB: NSObject
{}
 - (void)someMethod;
@end
```

calling code can look like this

```
- (void)someOtherMethodInAnOtherClassWithObject:(id)obj
{
  [obj someMethod];
}
```

This code will compile and will work fine at runtime, assuming `obj` is *either* an instance of `MyClassA` or `MyClassB`.

Of course, good practice would dictate that you define a `@protocol` in this situation:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
 - (void)myMethod
@end
```

and declare that your `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` both implement the `MyProtocol` protocol. Your calling code would then look like

```
- (void)someOtherMethodInAnOtherClassWithObject:(id<MyProtocol>)obj
{
  [obj someMethod];
}
```

and the compiler would give you a warning/error (depending on -W flags) if you tried to call `someOtherMethodInAnOtherClassWithObject:`, passing an object of a type that doesn't implement the `MyProtocol` interface.

Note that `id<MyProtocol>` is *not* a generic type, it's an instance of type `id` that you are claiming implements the `MyProtocol` protocol. Also note that the first version of client code works just fine because all that really maters is whether `obj` can respond to the `-myMethod` selector.

Comment: This is all true, but note that the original question is asking about static methods.